# Distributed Marketing Dynamic Content

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud, distributed-marketing

Are you not able to use dynamic content in an email you use for Distributed Marketing (DM)? If you have a DM DE, I would think that since Salescloud is writting to that DE dynamic content would work. However, I get an error on the Salescloud side stating to contact my MC Admin (me). When I delete the dynamic content in the email it sends successfully through Salescloud. This limitation does not seem to make sense to me. Is there a certain configuration that you need to make to enable this?

Comment: Can you share the content of your dynamic content block?

Comment: DM doesn't support dynamic content OOTB. There are options though, look up Customer Personalisations Interactions and Extend Entry Source on https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_dm_enhance_distributed_marketing.htm&type=5